# Is it an indication of weather change or does this character still have powers in the end?

Tags: plot-explanation, good-omens

In *Good Omens*, Adam rewrites reality so he would not be an antichrist anymore; but, near the end, when he took the Dog in the house garden but wished if the dog can run out so he can get chance to go out of the house too. Then the boundary plant/leaves turned dry to make a path for the dog to run out.

Does this indicate that Adam still has some powers or is it just an accelerated weather change indication?

Comment: How would the weather change so fast? Or was he waiting for a week until the plants dried? It looks quite clear to me.

Answer (score 6):

The character still has his powers, he just used them so the end of the world doesn't happen. As in, he used them to change just one simple fact of the world:

> Adam Young is the biological son of Satan who starts the Apocalypse.

into

> Adam Young is the biological son of Satan who doesn't start the Apocalypse.

He also fixed all the problems his previous "spells" caused and sometimes improved on previous state of the world, because he is a nice kid. But he is still a kid with magic powers, only he is using them relatively responsibly. He is not using them to do evil.

So what if he helps his dog run away? That's not evil, that's mischievous.

Edit: the situation from the Teen Titans cartoon kinda mirrors the one from Good Omens, where it is Raven vs her demonic father Trigon:

Comment: But as per my knowledge, he said something like satan is not his father

Comment: Relation by blood or relation by upbringing? :) Satan is his biological dad, that relation makes him Antichrist and gives him powers. Mr Young is his father, he brought him since he was a little baby. 
Similar situations: Yondu and Quil. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vcOojJ3IVw4
More fitting situation: Raven and Trigon:  https://youtu.be/K_cELuKKYog?t=42s

Comment: I will try to dig the quote later but as per my memory he said something like Young is being his birth father and by wishing that he rewrite history.

Comment: He is not his birth father, but he raised him since he was a baby. Mr Young is the only father Adam knows. He wished that he rewrote history as in "I wish that bad things didn't happen."